# Angular and URL rewrite capturing reverse proxy call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mod-rewrite

I am using Accusoft's document viewer in my Angular.js application. The only way to get to their services is to use a reverse proxy setup on one of my directories. Thus, I have set up "pas-service" which has a web.config in it as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The problem is that the site's redirect rules that are necessary for angular to work are capturing this before it can return the call and sending the index.html page back.

Here is what we have in our rewrite rules for the main part of the site:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RemovevesSeldetailsscripts" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*[/])scripts/(.*)$" />
          <conditions>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="scripts/{R:2}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Removevesseldetailscontent" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*[/])assets/(.*)$" />
          <conditions>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="assets/{R:2}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Main Rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(pas-service)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/jbv/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

How do I make the site's main rewrite rules ignore this reverse proxy request? What happens is that the request is this URL:

```
http://localhost/jbv/pas-service/Page/q/0?DocumentID=uZcjEtW-7NshOyh8iEIFCx-EbvHyIAuha6D7tbQvV77O_FKs_P-3KN7rB9McjnnisxhPFv1Wy0f7K4t_Hc0Cc6A&Scale=1&ContentType=svga
```

It simply redirects to the index.html page rather than returning the results of the call to the service. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using one set of rewrite rules? Instead of using two separate rules files, just add something like this to your main file:

```
<rule name="PasRewriteRule" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*[/])pas-service/(.*)$" />
  <conditions>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

Add this to the top, before your other rules, to make sure that it is matched first. You can then delete the Accusoft pas-service folder. Note that you may have to tweak the regular expression, since I am not sure of the exact setup of your application.